# How to use fabric when having multiple target in project

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an iOS project with 2 targets, I am trying to integrate fabric to the project. After following through their documentation I was able to implement crashlytics for first target and I am able to see the crash log in the dashboard also. Everything is working fine.

In the second target I used same API key and script which was used for first target then I tested the second app, in the dashboard I am able to see two different app reports.

Is it the right way to do it. I mean to use same API key for multiple targets.

Hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

API keys are set per organization within Fabric, so multiple apps or targets within the same Fabric organization would use the same key.